# How to convert a 1D signal to 2D signal?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, signal-processing, fft, medical-imaging

I have a 1 Dimensional signal (EEG signal) and I want to convert it to a 2D signal in order to use it as input for a CNN model. Can I use a Fourier transform to do that?

Comment: Hi, try giving more details about your problem, what you have tried, and the desired input/output

Comment: Try to build a CNN that takes a 1D input. You’ll be much better off than randomly adding a new, meaningless dimension.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I tried but accuracy was not good enough, I thought about using a 2d input

Comment: I support the Statement of Cris Luengo. Use a 1D Conv Layer. If you have a bad accuracy you should maybe raise your model complexity by adding additional conv layers or anything similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In here x instead of np.linspace use your data points (1D) array. Your 2D will be made up of (x,freq)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x)

## fourier transform
f = np.fft.fft(y)
## sample frequencies
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(y))
plt.plot(freq, abs(f) ** 2)
plt.show()

print( "Shape of singal array : {}".format(x.shape))

print( "Shape of frequency array : {}".format(freq.shape))

new_2D_array = np.vstack((x, freq)).T
print(new_2D_array)
```

Comment: what do you mean by data points ? (my input signal is EEG medical signal)

Comment: Sorry I am not very aware of the medical terms, but your EEG signal is a 1D array right ? If so, then perform the fourier transform to get the frecuency, thus you get  signal+frecuency .

Comment: Check the edit I made. When I mean data points , I mean your 1D array made up of the values from your EEG . You perform fourier transform on those points . Then you combine original EEG array + frecuency array, making a 2D array.

Comment: Even though EEG is medical it needs to be made up from values, I would think of amplitude or other. so you get  EEG_signal = [1,2,3,4,5,etc] -> 1D , the new array new_2d_array = [[1,F(1)], [2,F(2)] ...] hence 2D.

Comment: I wouldn’t want to do this, as the new dimension has no spatial relationship. OP wants to use a CNN, what does it mean to average f(i) and y(i) together?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you , one last question ! you think it would be better to use matlab or python ?

Comment: @wassimdiai: Use whatever language and whatever tool you're most comfortable with. "Better" is a subjective evaluation anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for a "spectrogram": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram
This is a 2D plot of amplitude vs time and frequency.

You make it by applying a short-time Fourier transform to successive overlapping portions of your signal.

Scipy has methods that will do this for you:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html

The number of frequencies is proportional to the window size (nperseg in the above docs).  You need to determine the appropriate frequency resolution for EEGs in order to set this.

Comment: The examples in the documentation add some noise to the original signal, does this affects the accuracy of the model??

Comment: Certainly it would affect the accuracy of the model.   I'm not sure exactly how, though.  If you're training a CNN, you may want to add some noise to prevent overtraining on minute details of the input.